# imp.load_source another file than .py , but a .py also exist in that directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I have this setup :

File :
a.ext1
a.py

a.ext1 loads a.py for some reason, but as an engine I need to load file a.ext1.

I can get it working fine in py3, but I cannot get it working in py2.

Here is my python2 attempt : ** This is the main flow, of course there is more code around it.

```
file = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('a.ext1')
directory = os.path.dirname(file)
sys.path.append(directory)
fullname = 'my.name.space.a'
sys.modules['my.name.space'] = imp.new_module('my.name.space')
x = imp.load_source(fullname,file)
```

Now, if I do ; x,  it will tell me:

```
module 'my.name.space' from '<path>/a.ext1'
```

but if I do dir(x) , it gives me  the stuff from a.py. I want it to give me the stuff from a.ext1 file.

How can I get this working on py2 ?

Here is how it works on py3 :

```
file = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('a.ext1'))
directory = os.path.dirname(file)
sys.path.append(directory)
fullname = 'my.name.space.a'
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(fullname = fullname, 
                                              path = file)
x = loader.load_module()
```

Now x is exactly what I want, the a.ext1 file, and not the .py

Any idea how I can get this working for py2 ?

(Btw i've read all I could find on this subject on Stack overflow,  but it was never the case where a .py also existed)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about the mumbo jumbo with creating empty modules and appending paths, but the very same works alright for me on 2.7. Definitely there shouldn't be a problem with a simple standalone example.

I'd say your `a.py` is being loaded into `my.name.space.a` as well, elsewhere in the program, in which case it's contents *clash* with whatever else you load under the same module name. There can only be a single global module instance of a given name at a time, e.g.:

a.py:

```
py_stuff = 1
```

a.ext1

```
ext1_stuff = 1
```

test-ok.py:

```
import imp

x = imp.load_source('a', 'a.ext1')

print(x) # <module 'a' from 'a.ext1'>
print(dir(x)) # ['__builtins__', ..., 'ext1_stuff']
```

test-not-ok.py:

```
import imp

import a

x = imp.load_source('a', 'a.ext1')

print(x) # <module 'a' from 'a.ext1'>
print(dir(x)) # ['__builtins__', ..., 'ext1_stuff', 'py_stuff']
```